# Load logback.xml from Manifest Class-path

Tags: java, logback

I'm trying to load `logback.xml` file from outside of my executable `myapp.jar` file.

The `myapp.jar` has a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file roughly like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: logger-config lib/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.18.jar lib/slf4j-api-1.7.18.jar 
Main-Class: com.mycompany.MyAppMain
```

and resides in

```
my-app/
  lib/
    jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.18.jar
    slf4j-api-1.7.18.jar 
  logger-config/
    logback.xml
  myapp.jar
```

(there is a lot of other jar dependencies, cut those out).

Now, if I run the application using `java -jar myapp.jar`, it starts OK, but it **does not pick up the logback.xml file**.

From their docs:

> If no such file is found, it checks for the file logback.xml in the classpath..

( http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html )

I know I can override this using `logback.configurationFile`, but is there a way to just put the XML file to classpath so that logback loads it automatically? It seems to work only if I package the `logback.xml` to `myapp.jar` (placing it in `src/main/resources` dir), but then the config file will be propagated to other JARs that uses `myapp.jar` as a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you just cut it out, but your classpath does not specify the `logback-classic` dependency. 
You will have to make sure `logback` appears before `slf4j` in your class-path definition. Also, note the trailing slash for the `logger-config` path - logback will not find your `logback.xml` without it (see [here](http://todayguesswhat.blogspot.co.at/2011/03/jar-manifestmf-class-path-referencing.html) for details).

Something like this should work:

```
Class-Path: lib/logback-classic-1.1.6.jar lib/logback-core-1.1.6.jar lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.18.jar lib/slf4j-api-1.7.18.jar logger-config/
```

Comment: seems to be the trailing slash! otherwise I had all the proper libraries, I just cut a lot of it out..